Deploying Laravel v11 to shared hosting cPanel
I'm trying to deploy a laravel version 11 but I got HTTP ERROR 500, I used FileZilla to transfer files because cPanel doesn't has SSH.
I followed some tutorials and moved the .htaccess, index.php from public directory to the public_html directory and changed the paths from ./../ to ./
and when I try to access a route like login it sends a forbidden error.
Index.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
    (require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php')
        ->handle(Request::capture());

.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php82” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

bootstap.app
In the cPanel I found a marked error x "syntax error" on the line of the return, I copied the code and put it on VS code and doesnot trigger any error ! so I don't know is this is the issue or not !!
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(append: [
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        ]);

I moved the .htaccess, index.php from public directory to the public_html directory and changed the paths from ./../ to ./
I checked the log files and it doesnot type any new errors. I searched  for errors in log and storage and I didnot find any new errors and tried using try and catch and it didnot return errors !!

Can you check your .log there must be more information about the problem.

If the log files do not yet contain any details, please use a higher error reporting level

I solved my issue which was the same as yours.
Dont move the .htaccess and index file from public instead just create a new .htaccess file inside your root directory (where .env and composer.json exist) and paste the following line of codes.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


the same problem, to make sure that I understand your answer correctly,
the tree should look like this
└── public_html
├── .htaccess             # your answer
├── public
│   ├── .htaccess         # the original .htaccess file of the public
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── robots.txt
│   └── assets            # Other assets like CSS, JS, images, build
the log files doesnot track the error they only track the error when I change the SQL configuration and does not even show me the default Laravel error page instead it present 500 HTTP Error

Exactly that is right,
But even now facing 500 issue please check the log file for details

All the log files are showing me old errors not updated and not even related, I actually need an error to solve it but the logs does not show any !! I don't know if it's because I'm deploying Laravel version 11 or not !! but I know the error is coming from here "->handle(Request::capture());" and I checked bootstap/app.php and I found a syntax error in the return line -Which doesnot have any syntax error in vs code-

I dont think that would be the issue, in deployment of laravel project, commonly there is issue with .htaccess files in root directory and / or with permission to storage directory, cause laravel need the enough permission to write files and remove files in log and caches.
